# Configuring GhostDoc to comment public accessors only

Tags: c#, xml-comments, ghostdoc

How can I configure GhostDoc to comment only public accessors only? I've looked at the "rules" configuration, but did not see any information/variables indicating accessor type.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Context.CurrentCodeElement.IsPrivate)
{
    throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

from http://community.submain.com/forums/thread/2993.aspx